# Find all documents where array is completely contained in another document's array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given the following documents in Mongo

```
{
'name': 'test1',
'members': [1, 2, 3]
},
{
'name': 'test2',
'members': [2, 3]
},
{
'name': 'test3',
'members': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

Find all documents in a collection where all 'members' in one array are totally contained within another document's 'members' array. For the documents above, the expected results would be projected in the following manner.

```
{
'shadowed': 'test1',
'shadowed_by': ['test3']
},
{
'shadowed': 'test2',
'shadowed_by': ['test1', 'test3']
}
```

Since test3 members are not completely contained in another document's members then no results would be provided for that.

The following query I feel gets me close except it only returns documents if the arrays are exactly the same.

```
db.objects.aggregate([
        {"$match": {}},
        {"$group" : { "_id": {"value": "$members"}, "objects": {"$addToSet":"$name"}, "count": {"$sum":1}}},
        {"$match": {"_id": {"$ne": null}, "count":{"$gte":2}}},
        {"$project": {"objects": 1, "value": "$_id", "_id":0}}
    ])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform a self-lookup with the conditions:

1. `_id` not equal to itself
2. `members` $setIsSubset`of the looked up`members`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "let": {
        members: "$members",
        id: "$_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $ne: [
                    "$$id",
                    "$_id"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$setIsSubset": [
                    "$$members",
                    "$members"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            name: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "shadowed_by"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      shadowed_by: {
        $ne: []
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      shadowed: "$name",
      shadowed_by: {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$shadowed_by",
          "as": "s",
          "in": "$$s.name"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xkrPiRastBu)

Comment: This does the job but man it is it extremely slow. I'm doing this over 57,000+ documents.

Comment: @r6danl99 How you index the collection?

Comment: @r6danl99 It supposed to be slow comparing to $group. $group is a single pass, while in $lookup you compare each document against whole collection. think like O(n^2) complexity.  You can optimise it a little, but the task is computationally heavy by nature - you asked how to compare each document with all other documents, and ray just shows you  how. If you can avoid it on application design level, it would be wise to do so. It's out of scope of the question tho.

Comment: @ray I created an index for the members field and it works much faster now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @r6danl99 updated the answer to use a more concise api `$setIsSubset`